# How to scroll character in a text field in Microsoft Edge?

Tags: javascript, scroll, microsoft-edge

My JavaScript file has this code:

```js
Obj.scrollLeft = Obj.scrollWidth;
```

This code is text-scrolling code. This code doesn't work in Microsoft Edge. Other browsers work fine.

*Microsoft Edge:*

[image: Scrolling issue in Microsoft Edge]

*Google Chrome:*

[image: No Scrolling Issue in Google Chrome]

=========================================================================
I'll share my example script.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<!--<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">-->

<script>

function textScroll()
{
    var inputObj = document.testFrm.text1;
    inputObj.scrollLeft = inputObj.scrollWidth; //text scrolling
}

</script>

</head>

<body>

<form name="testFrm" >
<input id="text1" type="text" size="10" value="wwwwwwwwwww123456789" /> 

</form> 

<button type="button" onclick="javascript:textScroll();">Scrolling text</button>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Run this script in Chrome and edges.
The results will differ from each other.
I want to know my JavaScript code why it does not operate in MS Edge.
Thank you.

Comment: Which build of Microsoft Edge do you have? See Settings, scroll to bottom.

Comment: You mean what settings?

Comment: Thank you for fix my wrong letters

Comment: Which version of Edge are you running? http://i.imgur.com/kWwfyQ7.gif

Comment: My version of Edge is 20.10240.16384.0.

Comment: Can you apply all updates in Windows Update, and see if this resolves the issue?

Comment: My Windows is already up to date.

Comment: Crystal, thank you for your patience. Build 10568 was released not too long ago for Windows 10 users; you should see it in Windows Updates. Your version of Edge is slightly out-dated. In the meantime, more information would be appreciated. Are you on a tablet, laptop, or desktop computer? Are you inputting with a soft-keyboard, or physical one? Over a wired connection (USB), or connected via Bluetooth? Also, can you share more of the surrounding code. Is there an eventListener in the area?

Answer (score 0):

It is supported in Edge.
Here is the version I used to validate it.

[image]

Also, it is having this behavior without having to do anything specific in the JS code.